# How to Track "Request Product" or "Save" configurations

Tags: json, shopify, roomle

I am trying to figure out how to add the capability to track conversions on Roomle. Right now I can only see the number of conversions, but nothing about the product(s) or the person's info. As our company really thrives off of leads/conversions. I was curious on how to go about getting the "Request Button" to work? I've tried multiple settings in the "Tenant Settings" section, but I can't seem to get anywhere with it. Here are my settings so far:

```js
{
    "showPrice": true,
    "useRoomlePrice": true,
    "unit": "inchfeet",
    "precisionInch": "0",
    "ls": "shelf_front",
    "emails": true,
    "onRequestProduct": true,
    "skin": {
        "brand-logo": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0516/5760/5278/files/logo-black_140x.png?v=1606838002",
        "primary-color": "black",
        "color-on-primary": "white",
        "font-color": "white"
    }
}
```

This is kind of what I am aiming for so we can generate some possible leads/follow up emails or phone calls:
[Roomle Example](https://www.roomle.com/en/documentation/rubens-configurator-request-processes)

Hopefully this all makes sense, if I need to explain further, or if there is anything else I can do to help make this happen, please let me know! I greatly look forward to your response!

Kind Regards,

Wade Morrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track which configurations led to a conversion (e.g. request product) you can add a callback to `onRequestProduct`, see https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#listen-to-onrequestproduct

The first param is the `configurationId` which identifies this exact configuration and can be used to load it again.

If you want to show a form to collect mail addresses you have to implement your own button and call `triggerRequestProduct` when clicked. This will then again trigger the callback `onRequestProduct` which should contain all the infos you'll need.

Comment: Oh okay, so it needs to be implemented through javascript interaction, not the embedding link then correct? Thank you for the help!

Comment: I've started to play around in the CodeSandobx and added the code snipit that Roomle has in the docu. I can get the console to log the callback, but I don't see where else it sends that information to. Would it send that information to my admin portal on Roomle? Or to an email of some sort?

Comment: This information is only available in your Javascript code, you can then choose what to do with it. For example calculating the price, adding the product to the basket or send an email with this configuration/image.